# Windows command/commands to FIND file and COPY it to certain location or directory where batch file was launched from

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, copy, find, command

So, I have started with this:

```
copy | dir /s /b | find "myFile" C:\Destination
```

but the problem is that the destination is not visible in this command. It only sees the first part of the command up until C:\Destination.

Is there a way I can search for a file and copy it?

I have also tried this:

```
SET source = dir /s /b | find "myFile"
SET destination = %CD%
copy %file% %destination%
```

but it doesn't work.

At some point even trying to set a variable that points to the current directory (`%CD%`) doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm looking for a solution that would work without installing anything new on the computer, that's why I'm thinking of batch files.

I think I could do this with VBscript but I'm not sure. If anyone thinks it's a better option please post that answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of work I have managed to find the right combination of commands in order to make this happen. Here it is for you all and I hope it helps:

```
SET destination=%CD%
E:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "searchedFile"') do (
cd ..
xcopy "%%a" "%destination%" /D:10-10-2011)
pause
```

I used the change directory command because the "directory" command returned the entire path, including the file and when trying to copy it.. it thought that the file was in the path that included its name.

For example, if i searched for "myFile.jpg" in "E:\Folder\New Folder\myFile.jpg" it thought that the location of the file was "E:\Folder\New Folder\myFile.jpg\myFile.jpg" and obviously this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`dir/s/b|for /f %i in ('find "myFile"') do copy "%i" .\`

Works very nicely for me.  Anyone know how to use the same line to copy same named files to a directory with new names.
Example:
file name is: text.txt
the above command line searches many folders and copies all instances found like below:
1text.txt, 2text.txt, 3text.txt

Answer (score 0):

Place the file path in quotes

```
copy "%file%" "%destination%"
```

or

```
SET destination = "%CD%"
```

Comment: No, quotes aren't the problem. I found the combination of commands, I just can't post my answer because I don't have enough bounty. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

dir/s/b|for /f %i in ('find "myFile"') do copy %i .\

---

Guess %i should be quoted, too...

dir/s/b|for /f %i in ('find "myFile"') do copy "%i" .\

Comment: I found the right combination by myself :) I just don't have enough reputation to post my own answer now. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @reos - The point of the website is to help everyone who comes here with a question and not just you right now. If there's a correct answer here, you should mark it for future visitors.

Comment: Your answers were more of hints than answers. I would mark my own answer as the correct one, but I am not allowed to mark my own answers until after 48 hours. So in the name of whoever else comes across this problem, I will mark a correct answer as soon as I am able to.

Comment: That's not a comment from whoever answered your question. And no one could answer you because you didn't make it clear in your question. And you screwed something, your cd.. just won't actually affect anything, because you used absolute path in your xcopy command.