# Batch file to find file, and copy paste it to another location

Tags: batch-file, copy, location, find, paste

needing help with batch file.
What I need: to find exact called file (for example from C: drive) and copy paste it to another location on same disk.

Example: I need to find file called "textfile.txt" from C: drive, and if it finds it, it will copy it, and paste to location C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer

So any simple way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows command/commands to FIND file and COPY it to certain location or directory where batch file was launched from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849904/windows-command-commands-to-find-file-and-copy-it-to-certain-location-or-directo) and [Batch to find file, copy file to another directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8955947/62576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d c:\textfile.txt') do copy /b "%%~i" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer"
```