# Using Batch to locate a file and copy it

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to search for a specific file name under the %SystemDrive% directory and subdirectories and directly copy it to a specified location using batch programming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d %SystemDrive%\textfile.txt') do copy /b "%%~i" "destination"`

textfile.txt is the file name, replace destination with the path to copy it to.
[was answered here already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669157/batch-file-to-find-file-and-copy-paste-it-to-another-location)